# Select String that is not a property of another object

Tags: c#, linq

I am writing code that will select string keys from an array **ApiIds** that are not property ApiId of results objects.

I wrote the following code, but it looks redundant to me, is there a way to combine this into one statement and not convert a HashSet of objects into another HashSet of Strings?

```
        var resultsCached = new HashSet<string>(results.Select(x => x.ApiId));
        var missingResults = apiIds.Select(x => !resultsCached.Contains(x));
```

Thanks.

Comment: this way looks reasonable to me. why do you want to change it?

Comment: Shorter is not necessarily better... especially in cases where any magic behind the shorter code is not well understood.. (not just original author, but also anyone who would read and maintain that code later).. An example would be, depending on what ilya means by "and not convert a HashSet of objects into another HashSet of Strings?" answers using `Except` below, may or may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Except` will give you the items that aren't in the other collection:

```
var missingResults = apiIds.Except(results.Select(x => x.ApiId));
```

Answer (score 1):

Another efficient O(n) approach is to use [`HashSet.ExceptWith`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875(v=vs.110).aspx) which removes all elements from the set which are in the second sequence:

```
HashSet<string> apiIdSet = new HashSet<string>(apiIds);
apiIdSet.ExceptWith(results.Select(x => x.ApiId));
```

The set contains only strings which are not in `results` now.